# Convert bytes to GB in each line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How can I convert bytes to gigabytes in each line in single column in Bash?
I have tried this:

```
echo "scale=2; $(cat file.log) / 1024^2" | bc
```

but that convert only last value.

Example of file.log content:

```
   2171863040
   1693491200
   1984045056
```

(without spaces between)

Comment: Can you provide `file.log`?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: ... and your desired output

Comment: Desired output is same column but in GB.

Comment: Don't just tell us about it - show the actual output you expect to get from your posted sample input in your question.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `awk`:

```
$ cat file.log
1073741824 1073741824

$ awk '{print $1/1024/1024/1024 " GB " $2/1024/1024/1024 " GB"}' file.log
1 GB 1 GB
```

or using the sample data you just posted:

```
$ awk '{print $1/1024/1024/1024 " GB "}' file.log
2.02271 GB
1.57719 GB
1.84779 GB
```

Answer (score 5):

`awk` will be faster -

```
awk '{ printf "%.2f\n", $1/1024/1024/1024; }' file.log
```

but `bc` needs a loop.

```
 while read b
 do bc <<< "scale=2; $b / 1024^3" # shouldn't GB be ^3?
 done < file.log
```

Both yield

```
2.02
1.58
1.85
```

## edit --

New upvote made me look at this again.
Comment elsewhere is inaccurate, but [has a valid point](https://www.techtarget.com/searchstorage/definition/mebibyte-MiB).

I am converting to ***gibi***bytes, which are powers of two, rather than ***giga***bytes, which are powers of ten. I assumed that was what was wanted, because of the technically incorrect usage in prevalence.

If OP actually ***meant*** they wanted powers of 10 instead of two, just switch the 1024's to 1000's -

```
awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) $i = ($i/(1000*1000*1000)); print }' file.log
```

...though I doubt that's what they meant, it is good to be clear, specific, and accurate.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for including the examples with limiting the decimal places ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to recalculate each field (space separated) in a row.

This `awk` script will do the work.

```
awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) $i = ($i/(1024*1024*1024)); print }' file.log
```

Comment: You are converting to MiB when OP wants to do GB.